# Copy files with long names

Tags: ubuntu, file-copy

I am on linux ubuntu 16 and I need to copy around 400gb(some 100.000 files) of data from my HDD to my SSD. This I can't do because around 1000 of those files have "too long name" and I can't just skip them since it will take a long time to find them. Any program that copies files with long names?

Comment: What filesystem is it that you're using that does not support these names? MSDOS? Would you be able to put the files in a `tar` archive and transfer that instead?

Comment: What filesystems are they? What are you using to copy the files? If something like `cp` on the command line, shouldn't you get an error printed out for them?

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to compare two lists of filenames. Try `cd /path1 && find . -type f | sort >/tmp/list1` then repeat for `path2` and `list2`. Use `sdiff /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2` to see differences or `comm -3 /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2` to see files in `list1` that aren't in `list2` and v.v.

Comment: If there's a limit on file name length, it's probably due to the filesystem(s), not to the tool you used. (I say “probably” because you didn't say which tool you used, so it's possible that you found some weird unusual tool that has a limitation.) What are examples of files whose name is too long, and what filesystem type are you copying them to?

Comment: Do you use home folder encryption? I'm asking because the home folder encryption Ubuntu uses prohibits files with a name longer than 144ish characters, whereas usually on ext{2, 3, 4}, you can use file names with up to 255 (not 255ish) characters.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Original (wrong) answer

Cool guys told, that `rsync` works like a charm:

```
rsync -auv --exclude '.svn' --exclude '*.pyc' source destination
```

Original answer: https://superuser.com/a/29437/483428

### UPD: with script

ok, other cool guys told, that `rsync` is not a solution, when **filesystem itself doesn't support long names**. I'll take note, that `rsync` is not a metaphysical low-level super secret tool, made by gods (there are a lot of such tools for Windows, btw;)

So, here is a short python script (python 2.7 is installed by default on Ubuntu, as I know), which copies all files from `SRC` to `DST`, and will print names of files, caused errors (including, long names)

1. Save it as `copy.py`
2. Usage: `python copy.py SRC DEST`

```python
import os
import sys
import shutil

def error_on_dir(exc, dest_dir):
    print('Error when trying to create DIR:', dest_dir)
    print(exc)
    print()

def error_on_file(exc, src_path):
    print('Error when trying to copy FILE:', src_path)
    print(exc)
    print()

def copydir(source, dest, indent = 0):
    """Copy a directory structure overwriting existing files"""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        if not os.path.isdir(root):
            os.makedirs(root)
        for each_file in files:
            rel_path = root.replace(source, '').lstrip(os.sep)
            dest_dir = os.path.join(dest, rel_path)
            dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, each_file)

            try:
                os.makedirs(dest_dir)
            except OSError as exc:
                if 'file exists' not in str(exc).lower():
                    error_on_dir(exc, dest_dir)

            src_path = os.path.join(root, each_file)
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(src_path, dest_path)
            except Exception as exc:
                # here you could take an appropriate action
                # rename, or delete...
                # Currently, script PRINTS information about such files
                error_on_file(exc, src_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg = sys.argv
    if len(arg) != 3:
        print('USAGE: python copy.py SOURCE DESTINATION')
    copydir(arg[1], arg[2])
```

Comment: `rsync` is a great tool but your answer doesn't address the `Filename too long` error we are told is reported during a copy.

Comment: You might at least remove the parts that aren't relevant to the situation you're answering, instead of directly copy-pasting the answer

Comment: @roaima, ok, you are right. But it would be better to point, that the answer is not appropriate, bcz the problem is **filesystem limitations**, and rsync doesn't solve them. Anyway, thanks for your comment;)

Comment: @ilkkachu it would be better to mention which options are not relevant, than just complain in comments. I tried to help, I found that `robocopy` solves such problem on Win, and `rsync` - is a good alternative for `robocopy` , I used `rsync` for data-backup, but not so often, to know all its options. If you know how - share your knowledge;)

Comment: Rsync worked perfectly and didn't have the same issue as the terminal "copy" nor my file managers way of copying files where it spit out errors on files with long names.